# Using both Firebase Realtime Database and Firestore with same ID

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Like the title suggests, I have a use case where I will write data to both firestore and realtime database. I am using the realtime database for operations that require live feedback to users and firestore to store data that will not really change but can be queried for more complex operations later on.

Due to my need of both databases, I would like to use the same UID when creating data in both databases to make it easy to retrieve in the future. The issue I have is determining which generated ID will satisfy the other service.

My thought process is since Realtime Database push ID is based on timestamp, it could create hot partitions for Firestore so indexing performance as data grows could get hurt in the future if I used the same ID there. But if I use firestore's generated ID in the realtime database, I will not have the data in the sorted fashion that realtime database creates pushed data.

I was wondering what solutions people used to tackle this use case and what options are available to me. Thanks!

Comment: I question the need to use two databases for the reasons you state here.  Firestore is perfectly capable of serving realtime results just like Realtime Database.  Using both of them together seems to be adding complexity and cost unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to order data, then simply store timestamps as fields instead of depending on the time-based sort order of Realtime Database push IDs.  You can do this easily in both databases.  Firestore makes obsolete the idea that unique IDs have any meaning other than simply being unique.

If you make sure your unique ID's are truly random like Firestore's, then you won't have any problems with indexing or writing documents.